# PySpark - Creating a single column from multiple columns with some basic math

Tags: pyspark

Consider the following PySpark dataframe

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A, B | D, G | A, G |
| C, F | C, D | A, G |
| C, F | C, D | A, G |

I'd like to create a new dataframe with 2 columns, the first with all the different combinations, and the second column is the ratio: Frequency of Combination / Total Number of Combinations. For example,

| Combination | Ratio |
| --- | --- |
| A, B | 0.111 (1/9) |
| C, F | 0.222 (2/9) |
| D, G | 0.111 (1/9) |
| C, D | 0.222 (2/9) |
| A, G | 0.333 (3/9) |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpivot, then group by and count:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.selectExpr(
    'stack(' + str(len(df.columns)) + ', ' + ', '.join(df.columns) + ') as combination'
).groupBy('combination').count().withColumn(
    'ratio', 
    F.col('count') / F.sum('count').over(Window.orderBy())
).drop('count')

df2.show()
+-----------+------------------+
|combination|             ratio|
+-----------+------------------+
|       A, B|0.1111111111111111|
|       C, F|0.2222222222222222|
|       C, D|0.2222222222222222|
|       D, G|0.1111111111111111|
|       A, G|0.3333333333333333|
+-----------+------------------+
```